# Is こら a lot more rude than ほら?

Tags: word-choice, interjections

From early on, I've used `こら` and `ほら` somewhat interchangeably. They both mean "hey!"

I picked them up from friends early on without really having a sense of the difference.

Now, after some time, I've come to understand that `ほら` is simply "hey!", as in just getting someone's attention, and `こら` is "hey" with a flavour of "dude, what the hell?" mixed in.

The thing is, I still tend to slip and use `こら` when maybe I should say `ほら`, and vice versa. Old habits die hard.

My question is, when I mix up and say `こら` instead of `ほら`, how bad is it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[こら](http://www.excite.co.jp/dictionary/japanese/?search=%E3%81%93%E3%82%89&match=beginswith&itemid=DJR_kora_-020) is uttered usually when the speaker is scolding or blaming someone.  [ほら](http://www.excite.co.jp/dictionary/japanese/?search=%E3%81%BB%E3%82%89&match=beginswith&itemid=DJR_hora_-030) is used to draw someone’s attention to something.  They are not interchangeable.

I do not know how bad it is to mix them up, especially if other people know that you speak Japanese as a foreign language, but using こら in an inappropriate situation can be rude and may give the impression that you consider that you are superior to the addressee.

Comment: You also can't roll your Rs with ほら: ほるるるるらーっ！ Nope, doesn't sound right.

Comment: What about when you are drawing someone's attention to the following scolding your about to give them?